# iOS Action Extension not being installed

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension

Yesterday I added the first action extension to my (iOS) app. Everything worked well (after I figured out how to configure the NSExtension dict).

Today I added the second action extension (to the same app) and configured it almost the same way (except the icon and bundle id, obviously). When I wanted to actually use the extension, I couldn't find it. It seems like the second extension hasn't been installed.

I cleaned the app target and the extension target, I deleted the derived data folder, I deleted the app from the device (and simulator) and I removed and re-added the extension from the app target (embedded binaries). Nothing helped. I tried it on a real device and on the simulator, and I tried it on 8.0 and 8.1.

Has anybody else ever experienced this? Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! The issue has been caused by the asset catalog file. When I selected "Use Asset Catalog" for the extension icon I unchecked "Also migrate launch images". Because of the latter, a bug in Xcode selected the wrong asset catalog and messed up my other asset catalogs. Of course I selected the right asset catalog afterwards and cleaned up the others, but it seems like Xcode didn't recognize the actual selected asset catalog and thus didn't copy the icon, what caused the disappearance of the extension.

I deleted and re-created the extension target several times and now it seems to work. I can use the extension and it uses the correct icon.